# How to combine audio and video using FFmpeg and sync them?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm trying to convert Adobe Connect Recording which consists of multiple FLV files. Some have the audio and some have the video.
I want to combine the FLV files into a single video.
BUT, there is an important requirement. I want to start playing the audio/video at a specific time.
For example:

```
audio1.flv start at 0s
audio2.flv start at 20s
video1.flv start at 15s
video2.flv start at 160s
```

So how can I tell FFmpeg which FLVs to use as audio, and which ones to use as video, as well as when to start playing each one of them?

Comment: Need to see info about each input to provide an accurate answer. Run `ffmpeg -i audio1.flv -i audio2.flv -i video1.flv -i video2.flv`, then copy and paste the complete log.

Comment: @llogan I updated the question with the info you requested : )

Comment: I thought there were 4 input files. Also, that's not the **complete** output.

Comment: @llogan I found the `itsoffset` command, but I don't know how to use it to concat multiple inputs. For example `ffmpeg -i input1.flv -itsoffset 25 -i input2.flv -itsoffset 150 -i input3.flv -c copy -y combined_output.flv`. Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: `-itsoffset` is not the solution. I have a method for you using adelay and tpad filters, but I've been waiting for the requested info so I can give you a command you can copy and paste.

Comment: @llogan I'm trying to create a program that converts any Adobe Connect Recording, so I can't just copy/paste a command. Instead, please explain to me how your method works so I can automate it in my program. Thanks : )

Comment: Then I must make a blind, generic answer that will require additional work on your part.

Comment: @llogan it's not blind if you know the requirements :p Basically, I want to have a list of delayed FLVs, and only take their Audio. And a second list of delayed FLVs, and only take their Video. And the output will be the audio list + the video list combined.

Answer (score 0):

## Using the concat demuxer

This uses the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) source filter to create 15 second black video spacer to put in the beginning:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=640x480:r=25:d=15 blank.flv
```

This needs to match all of the attributes of the other videos including width, height, pixel format, frame rate (ideally), video format, container format, timebase, etc.

Create input list files for the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

Example `video.txt`:

```
file 'blank.flv'
file 'video1.flv'
file 'video2.flv'
```

Example `audio.txt`:

```
file 'audio1.flv'
file 'audio2.flv'
```

Then concat:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i video.txt -f concat -i audio.txt -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest output.flv
```

Make sure all inputs have the same attributes before concatenating. If they vary then it may fail or have undesirable results, and you'll need to pre-process them using various filters before concatenating, or see below.

## Using filters

Filtering requires re-encoding, so you can't stream copy a filtered stream, but you can do it all in one command and the output can be more consistent than using the concat demuxer (due to users trying to concatenate arbitrary, dissimilar inputs).

Use the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) (delay audio), [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) (downmix audio), [tpad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) (delay video), and [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.flv -i audio2.flv -i video1.flv -i video2.flv -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=20s[a1];[2:v]tpad=start_duration=15[v0];[0:a][a1]amix[a];[v0][3:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest  output.flv
```

Due to a lack of information regarding your inputs this is a generic answer that makes some assumptions:

- All inputs have the same attributes. This is required for proper concatenation. If this is not the case then add additional filters to make all attributes the same before using concat.
- I am assuming that the duration of `video1.flv` is 145 seconds, and you want `video2.flv` to play when `video1.flv` ends which occur at 160 seconds (145 + 15 delay).
- Make sure to use a recent `ffmpeg` or you'll get an error from adelay not supporting the `s` (seconds) suffix: in that case upgrade or use milliseconds instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I couldn't use `-c copy` with these filters : ( The videos all contain the same format and resolutions etc... so I don't know why `copy` doesn't work. The recordings are several hours each, and re-encoding them will take forever especially on slow PCs : ( is there a faster way?

Comment: I think a faster solution is to generate delayed FLV files, and then concat them with the corresponding video/audio file. How can I generate mute/dark FLV files with a specified duration?

Comment: @Amire You can't filter and stream copy the same stream. You should have mentioned no filtering as a requirement. If each input is shown in a linear fashion the the concat demuxer is an option. If there is any overlap then filtering is required. You did not specific if the inputs are to be played one after the other, or if there are any of the same stream types playing at the same time. For example, does audio2 overlay audio1? Does video2 overlay video1?

Comment: nothing overlays. Audio FLVs are supposed to play one after the other, and the same thing for Video FLVs. The requirement is to add delay to the FLVs (Audio + Video), and then concat them into one flv output. A solution without re-encoding will be perfect. I tried `-ss 0 -i video1.flv -t 1 -c copy fragment_1s.flv`, then created a file `input.txt`, and added `file fragment_1s.flv` multiple times (for example 10 times for 10 seconds), and then added `file video1.flv` and then `-f concat -i input.txt -c copy`, but the output video has issues... I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @Amire See updated answer.